# Listen keyboard shortcuts (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

How can i run a method when someone used a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> ?

The application is a Windows forms application and i only want to capture it when the form is activated.

Comment: Some hint about whether this is a Winforms app, Silverlight, WPF, Console App, ASP.NET etc would help

Comment: Do you want to do global keyboard hook and intercept the shortcut in any application, or just your specific application?

Comment: thanks for the hints. added more details :)

Answer (score 4):

Keyboard shortcuts are often referred to as "command keys". If you want first-crack at keypresses (before your child controls), the best place is to override the ProcessCmdKey method on your form.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your OnKeyPress method on the Form or the KeyPress event for the Form.

Override the OnKeyPress like this...

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e) { ... }
```

... and look at the KeyPressEventArgs to see what key was pressed and whether it was pressed with Ctrl.

This SO answer shows how to use the KeyPress event...
[Test for 'Ctrl' keydown in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143567/test-for-ctrl-keydown)

Comment: This won't work if you have child controls that take keyboard focus.